# Sizing JQuery Dialog with iFrame

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

My requirement is to show a page (iFrame) as a Modal window. 
What I am noticing is that the iFrame content takes up only a small-pre-defined space even though the Dialog window is given height/weight of 100%

I used 2 jquery widget example pages to try this.

The [main page](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwYxA85P9A4mV0Y1NHIwNC1JMExxMmlWbVhIb002S1N0Z25j/edit?pli=1) and the [modal content](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwYxA85P9A4mYlVwM25pX2w4TGNDb3M5cG1uM2duZkFSQVBj/edit?usp=sharing)

Can the content width/height be changed to take 100% of the dialog window?
Thanks

Comment: You can define a style for `#dialog-modal iframe` and set its `width` and `height` to `100%`.

Comment: Thank you very much!!. It worked for me.
Could you please post this as answer, so that I can mark it? Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a style for `#dialog-modal iframe` and set its `width` and `height` to `100%`